# Angular 12 | Components rendered without adding it to declarations in module

Tags: angular, module, components

So I have recently started working on Angular and trying to clear my concepts of how components and modules work and how they interact with each other.

I have an AppComponent that has a router-outlet and is added in the declaration of AppModule. But the other two components are not added to the declaration (login and page not found components) rather these two are added to the app routing module as Routes. Based on my understanding login and page not found components should not render in the browser unless I add them to declarations in AppModule but right now they do render fine. I want to understand why?

I have shared code from app module and app routing module below.

**App Module**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DealerModule } from './ng-modules/dealer.module';

export const str: string = "sample string from Login Module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DealerModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**App Routing Module**

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { PagenotfoundComponent } from "./modules/core/pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./modules/login/login/login.component";

const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PagenotfoundComponent
  }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)
  ], exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Dealer Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DealerRoutingModule } from './dealer-routing.module';
import { LayoutComponent } from '../modules/core/layout/layout.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LayoutComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DealerRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class DealerModule { }
```

**Dealer Routing Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from '../modules/core/layout/layout.component';
import { AdddealerComponent } from '../modules/dealers/adddealer/adddealer.component';
import { ListdealersComponent } from '../modules/dealers/listdealers/listdealers.component';

const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'adddealer', component: AdddealerComponent },
      { path: 'listdealers', component: ListdealersComponent }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(AppRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class DealerRoutingModule { }
```

As you can see in case of DealerRoutingModule, I have not added AddDealerComponent and ListDealersComponent in declaration but they render on browser as well.

Just to be clear LayoutComponent does not have a module either. It is only used as a master layout to carry navbar and siderbar and a router outlet for AddDealer and ListDealers Components.

if I remove Layout Component from declaration in Dealer Module the app would through compile time exception. How is it that Layout Component is required in declaration but AddDealer and ListDealers Components are not?

Comment: A component in angular has to be declared in at least one module, which then can be imported in other modules. From what I see here I would expect that AppModule at least imports modules of LoginComponent and PageNotFoundComponent. Instead we see the import of DealerModule. Does this Module imports/declares the other components?

Comment: @LukaszGawrys I have not added separate modules for LoginComponent and PageNotFoundComponent as of yet. DealerModule has two separate components and its own routing module. let me update my answer to add code for Dealer Module as well.

Comment: Ok, this is interesting and it seems that since the ivy engine it is not true anymore, that all components have to be declared in a module. It seems particularly that it is not necessary for simple components which are rendered through ```router-outlet```  what would explain the case you provided. ```LayoutComponent``` has to be declared because it contains router-outlet itself, but the other components are only rendered within it. Before ivy it wouldn't work but now it seems to be ok.

Comment: I’m suprised this works..? Must be a 12 thing as this doesn’t seem to work in v11..

Answer (score 1):

the declare / import statements are **angular** (and not **TypeScript**) and they are required for rendering a component in `html` via the `selector` property,

**BUT**

if you simply *export* a class from a **TypeScript** file and *import* it in another **TypeScript** file it would work since it is a simple TypeScript execution,

since you tell it the exact file it can find the component (the TS Class):

```
import { LoginComponent } from "./modules/login/login/login.component";
```

then it is possible, if you would try to refer to the component as part of a lib in the format of:

```
import { LoginComponent } from '@MyWorkspace/login';
```

it will surely fail

the `router` also uses a **TypeScript** call, and does not need the `selector-to-calss` reflection, so it does not use or need angular declaration / export mechanism